# clarification in spring security regarding field names?

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I am using spring security for authentication. i have two fields, email and password. usually names field names should be `j_username` and `j_password`. it it mandatory to keep their names as is?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the form field names and the URL that the form processes by using the appropriate [namespace attributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-form-login). Alternatively, if you're using `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` directly you can inject the parameter names there.

A namespace example might be:

```
<form-login login-processing-url="/login.do" username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password" />
```

It's a good idea to override the default parameter names and URL as it makes it less obvious to someone browsing your site what technologies you are using in your application.